# Why there no div elements on a page?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple page using html and ccs only, it contains two colored div blocks which isn't rendered on a page: there should be yellow and green div's appear on a page, but instead blank page.
I checked for an errors - browser shows no errors.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Keyboard Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="field"></div>
<div class="key" id="a key"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.field {
 background-color:yellow; 
}

.key {
 background-color: green;
}
```

They both in the same folder, name of files containing html and css are `index.html`  and `styles.css`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add some `padding` or `content`

```css
.field {
 background-color:yellow; 
 padding:20px;
}

.key {
 background-color: green;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Keyboard Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="field">test</div>
<div class="key" id="a key">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

the `divs` are empty so their computed height is `0`.
Use a `min-height` or add a character like a `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 3):

Because they're empty.

```
<div class="field">text</div>
<div class="key" id="a key">text</div>
```

put something in them and youll see them

Answer (score 2):

The divs are empty, ie they have no children and have no height assigned. If you add content to the divs, such as images or text or give them some sort of height property, you will see them.

Answer (score 2):

You don`t have any dimensions.
Add them like this:

```css
.field {
  background-color:yellow;
  height: 50px;
}
    
.key {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block element and when you use it it expect some content from you.
You can make the `div`s visible in following ways:

```css
div{
min-height:27px;
}

.heights-a{
background-color:green;
}
.heights-b{
background-color:yellow;
}

.space-div{
background-color:orange;
}

.content-div{
background-color:white;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

.chakar{
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid blue;
width:25px;
height:24px;
position:absolute;
left:44%;
top:0%
}
```

```html
<!-- Using Space-->
<div class="space-div">&nbsp; </div>

<!-- Using Content-->
<div class="content-div">
<div class="chakar">
</div>

</div>

<!-- Using Height-->
<div class="heights-a"></div>

<div class="content-div"> INDIA!!!</div>
```